# passing String parameter using Intent in Android

Tags: android

I am trying to parse a website that searches by content1 or content2 depending which button is clicked. I have an algorithm that works fine, but I was asked to make it in two classes. I hope it's not gonna make me change my whole algorithm. But yet, I am troubling sending string parameters to the new activity and I hated it.

I defined global parameters:

```
String content1;
String content2;
```

I need to get string in an EditText whose names are "namesurname" and "district":

```
content1 = district.getText().toString();
content2 = namesurname.getText().toString();
```

I have two buttons that have listeners:

```
    search1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent search = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            search.putExtra("param_a", content1);
                    startActivity(search);
        }               
    });
    search2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent search = new Intent(AvukatParserActivity.this, ParserActivity.class);
            search.putExtra("param_b", content2);
        startActivity(search);
        }
    });
```

From now on, my SecondActivity.class shows up.

I am trying to get intent in the new activity:

```
    Intent search = getIntent();
    String location = search.getStringExtra("param_a");
    String name_surname = search.getStringExtra("param_b");
```

Here's how I check my content1:

```
Toast.makeText(this, location, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It toastes as null as content2. No errors, no warnings. I don't get what I'm doing incorrect. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where you put  content1 = district.getText().toString();

Comment: @DheereshSingh to the first class, where my EditText defined and added to the layout.

Comment: basically I want ask you need to get data from edit text when you clicked the search1 button as in anwser http://stackoverflow.com/a/10945312/804447

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. each of the listeners put only a single value into the intent instead of both , and the toast shows only one of them .
2. about this code:

   ```
   content1 = district.getText().toString();
   content2 = namesurname.getText().toString();
   ```

   put it inside the onClick methods , and then tell us if it helped . 
   i'm guessing you put the old values there , so it gets null instead of the updated values.

Comment: excellent explanation. thank you. without putting getText().toString() methods to inside of onClick() methods, content1 and content2 values are not changed, so they initialized null before so I realised it thanks to Dheeresh Singh

Comment: yes i wasn't sure this was the problem , so i've written some advices instead. the best clue for the problem was that you get a null , yet the content cannot be null since you call "toString" , and it doesn't make sense that such a method to return null . anyway , i've edited my answer to be clearer for others.

Comment: it makes sense actually because I didn't call toString method after I edited the EditText so it calls the initialized one. When I set a default text to EditText, null value changed.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line

```
 search1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           content1 = district.getText().toString(); //if district is gloaal and has been set in onCreate
            Intent search = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            search.putExtra("param_a", content1);
                    startActivity(search);
        }               
    });
```

Comment: thank you, it just sorted it out! but I need to intent seperate classes I believe, because toastes are not proper and one of them is always null, depending on what I don't know

Comment: now I have another issue :) I need to write the content1 value in the second class to a TextView. I mean, I want to print it with TextView, not with Toast. "process stopped unexpectedly" says emulator.

Comment: check 2 things  1- you have set the setContentView in onCreate 2- you are using right id in findViewById which is after setContentView in Oncreate......

Comment: it's resolved, I used a different .xml file.. Thanks but I have another question, can I search or parse TextView? if cannot, I will create a new algorithm which I don't want to :(

Comment: sorry, but  search from where?

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();//make it global
search1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           content1 = district.getText().toString(); //if district is gloaal and has been set in onCreate
            Intent search = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            bundle.putString("param_a",content1);
            search.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(search);
        }               
    });
search2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           content2 = namesurname.getText().toString(); //if district is gloaal and has been set in onCreate
            Intent search = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            bundle.putString("param_b",content2);
            search.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(search);
        }               
    });
```

in second activity onCreate

```
Budle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();

String username=bundle.getString("param_b");
String location=bundle.getString("param_a");
```